# php:5-apache container does not load any pages

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I try to convert this [original](https://github.com/qunfengdong/mGSV/) project into a docker-compose project [here](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker) and followed a their setup [instructions](https://github.com/qunfengdong/mGSV/blob/master/INSTALLATION). It seems that I am not able to connect with the browser and I am not quite sure which IP address should I use inside the browser.

The [SQL file](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/blob/master/mysql/mgsv.sql) contains the database schema and looks like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mgsv;
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'mgsv_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mgsvpass';
use mgsv;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userinfo` (
    `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email` text NOT NULL,
    `hash` text NOT NULL,
    `synfilename` text NOT NULL,
    `annfilename` text NOT NULL,
    `url` text NOT NULL,
    `session_id` text NOT NULL,
    `annImage`   int(5) NOT NULL,
    `create_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

The [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) looks like this:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mgsv
      - MYSQL_USER=mgsv_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mgsvpass
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql123
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  www:
    build: ./mGSV 
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

And the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/blob/master/mGSV/Dockerfile) contains PHP and all other tools setup and looks like this.

```
FROM php:5-apache

RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
                openjdk-7-jdk \
                maven  \
        git \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN git clone https://github.com/qunfengdong/mGSV.git

# Move the folder 'mgsv' to DocumentRoot of Apache web server. By default, the DocumentRoot of Apache is /var/www/ (speak to the system administrator to know the exact DocumentRoot).
RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV \
    && mkdir tmp \
    && chmod -R 777 tmp

RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV && sed -i.bak "s|'gsv'|'mgsv_user'|" lib/settings.php \ 
    && sed -i.bak "s|$database_pass = ''|$database_pass = 'mgsvpass'|" lib/settings.php \
    && sed -i.bak "s|cas-qshare.cas.unt.edu|localhost|" lib/settings.php

RUN cp /var/www/html/mGSV/Arial.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/

#Do not understand
#7. Cleanup scripts are provided to drop database synteny and annotation tables, remove entries from database table 'userinfo' and delete the folder containing image files which are older than 60 days. This task is accomplished by cron job to run the cleanup script every day. To create a cron job, use the command below:
#   shell> crontab -e

#At the last line of crontab, copy and paste the line below, and provide the exact path to mgsv/lib/cleanup.php
#   30 04 * * * /var/www/mgsv/lib/cleanup.php

#The script cleanup.php will be executed at 4:30 AM every morning.

#8. mGSV uses the mail function from PHP to send email to users. Speak to your system administrator to provide required information in the PHP configuration file called 'php.ini'.

#9. When installation completes, you can now open Install/index.php (i.e., http://<YOUR_SERVER_DOMAIN_NAME>/mgsv/Install/), which verifies prerequisites, database setup, and installation. YOUR_SERVER_DOMAIN_NAME refers to the domain name of your server.


RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV/ws \
    && tar -xzf mgsv-ws-server.tar.gz

RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV/ws/mgsv-ws-server \ 
    && mvn package

RUN cp -f /var/www/html/mGSV/ws/mgsv-ws-server/target/ws-server-1.0RC1-jar-with-dependencies.jar /var/www/html/mGSV/ws/

RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV/ws \ 
    && echo "mgsv_upload_url=http://localhost/mgsv" > config.properties \
    && echo "ws_publish_url=http\://localhost\:8081/MGSVService" >> config.properties \
    && java -jar ws-server-1.0RC1-jar-with-dependencies.jar &

#To stop the web service
#shell> ps aux | grep ws-server-1.0RC1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
#*Note the process id from the output*
#shell> kill -9 <process id>
```

This is the output which I got:

```
Attaching to mgsvdocker_www_1, mgsvdocker_db_1
www_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.20.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
www_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.20.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
www_1  | [Tue Mar 20 09:10:15.169271 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) PHP/5.6.34 configured -- resuming normal operations
www_1  | [Tue Mar 20 09:10:15.179888 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
db_1   | Initializing database
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:15.257263Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:15.691035Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:15.784185Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:15.857675Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 80eed3e7-2c1e-11e8-97b3-0242ac140003.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:15.859294Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:15.860077Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:18.098720Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:18.099178Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:18.099722Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:18.100022Z 1 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:18.100235Z 1 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:18.100458Z 1 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:18.100728Z 1 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:18.100952Z 1 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | Database initialized
db_1   | Initializing certificates
db_1   | Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
db_1   | .....................+++
db_1   | ................................+++
db_1   | unable to write 'random state'
db_1   | writing new private key to 'ca-key.pem'
db_1   | -----
db_1   | Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
db_1   | .........................................................+++
db_1   | .....+++
db_1   | unable to write 'random state'
db_1   | writing new private key to 'server-key.pem'
db_1   | -----
db_1   | Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
db_1   | .+++
db_1   | ...+++
db_1   | unable to write 'random state'
db_1   | writing new private key to 'client-key.pem'
db_1   | -----
db_1   | Certificates initialized
db_1   | MySQL init process in progress...
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.678069Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.680166Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.21) starting as process 87 ...
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.684113Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.684403Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.684570Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.684740Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.684914Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.685080Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.685529Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.685843Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.689476Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.709888Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.712997Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.728051Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.741954Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.742914Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.813476Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.816581Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.816607Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.817193Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.867506Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.21 started; log sequence number 2551166
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.868332Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.871577Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.873341Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180320  9:10:21
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.887170Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.888550Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.902540Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.911559Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.911597Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.911646Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.911655Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.911676Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.914000Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.914021Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.943073Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:21.943488Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1   | Version: '5.7.21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:25.052819Z 4 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:25.053326Z 4 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:25.053640Z 4 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:25.055825Z 4 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:25.056427Z 4 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:25.057438Z 4 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:25.058141Z 4 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:25.058571Z 4 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
db_1   | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
db_1   | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
db_1   | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:25.147658Z 8 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:25.147712Z 8 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:25.147734Z 8 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:25.147785Z 8 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:25.147797Z 8 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:25.147820Z 8 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:25.148087Z 8 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:25.148104Z 8 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 
db_1   | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mgsv.sql
db_1   | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
db_1   | 
db_1   | 
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:25.180041Z 0 [Note] Giving 1 client threads a chance to die gracefully
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:25.180071Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.180217Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.180258Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.180343Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181049Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181062Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181067Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181073Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181078Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181100Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181106Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181118Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181124Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181129Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181134Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181138Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181143Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181147Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181152Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181157Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181161Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181166Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181170Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181175Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181180Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181184Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181189Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181194Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181198Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181203Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181207Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181212Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181217Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181221Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181226Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181231Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181235Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181240Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181245Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181249Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181254Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181258Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.181820Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.182259Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.284343Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:27.285555Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 180320  9:10:27
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.703178Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 12318903
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.705491Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.705927Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.706135Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.706295Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.706445Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.706709Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.707464Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
db_1   | 
db_1   | 
db_1   | MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
db_1   | 
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.946862Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.949405Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.21) starting as process 1 ...
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.954560Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.955010Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.955256Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.955444Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.955625Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.955799Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.956319Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.956783Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.962120Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.991836Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:28.999976Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.015271Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.052473Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.057927Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.126989Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.128627Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.128761Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.131502Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.186824Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.21 started; log sequence number 12318903
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.187457Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.190693Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.204188Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.207621Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.242030Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180320  9:10:29
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.251628Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.253243Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.253563Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.253772Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.264754Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.264814Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.264830Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.264849Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mgsv_user@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.264877Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.264885Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.264906Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.282969Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.283006Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.309033Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db_1   | 2018-03-20T09:10:29.315011Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1   | Version: '5.7.21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
db_1   | 2018-03-20T23:26:16.812251Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 51248773ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
```

I am not quite sure whether I did a mistake in the [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file or database configuration inside the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/blob/master/mGSV/Dockerfile#L16-L18).

```
RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV && sed -i.bak "s|'gsv'|'mgsv_user'|" lib/settings.php \ 
    && sed -i.bak "s|$database_pass = ''|$database_pass = 'mgsvpass'|" lib/settings.php \
&& sed -i.bak "s|cas-qshare.cas.unt.edu|localhost|" lib/settings.php
```

By any chance, do anyone know what I am missing because it does not load anything inside the browser and from the log files it appears that I did not make any connection to the docker image?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm guessing you're missing a link or network to join your www container with your db container. In your current docker-compose, without a link or a shared network, www can't see your db container. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links

Comment: Hi,

First all the containers defined in a docker compose can see each other, without link.
Your docker is installed on your PC or on a VM/remote host? If locally, the URL should be http://localhost:8080, else IP:8080.

Comment: what does this have to do with `java` other than you install it in the container?

Comment: localhost:8080 opened me a page of Admire 4.6.2 . According the [documentation](https://github.com/qunfengdong/mGSV/blob/master/INSTALLATION#L87) the service should run on `localhost:8080/mgsv/Install/` but I it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: It works after I changed inside `docker-compose.yml` in www -> ports to `8080:80`